# Is there a way to make Jetty use SSL with java Code

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, osgi, equinox

I have an `Eclipse RCP` Project with an `Equinox Jetty` Web Server. I want the Jetty Server to use `SSL`.

I tested setting the Attributes in the Run Configuration of Eclipse and it works fine.

```
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.https.enabled=true
...
```

Now my Question: Is there a programmatic way to make `Jetty` use `SSL`?

Comment: You could set this system property at your program's startup in Java code.

Comment: @Thilo
I'm looking for an other way to configer Jetty.
Somthing like this:
     JettyBundle.stopServer();
     JettyBundle.startServer(specialConfigs);

Answer (score 0):

Add a SSLConnector to your list of connectors like

```
SslConnector sslConnector = new SslSelectChannelConnector(sslContextFactory);
```

Comment: This is not so easy, because in an OSGi environment the Jetty server is started from it's own bundle.

Comment: Is there any possibility to setup the environment via XML (I'm not used to OSGi).

Comment: Might it be possible with a bundle fragment?